# Cypress - Compare equality of two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, chai, cypress

Using Cypress (just started), I can't find a way to assert the equality of text in the two input boxes as in the picture. The use case is that when a user sets a pickup location, by default the same location should appear in the drop off box.

[image]

To test the above, I wrote this code:

```
  cy.get('input#dropFtsAutocomplete').should("have.value" , cy.get('input#ftsAutocomplete'));
```

Correctly, Cypress complains with the following error:

> Error:    AssertionError: expected
>   '' to have
>   value { Object (chainerId, firstCall) }, but the value was 'Manchester
>   Airport (MAN), Manchester, United Kingdom'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve this just follow the Cypress FAQ:

```
cy.get('input#ftsAutocomplete').invoke('val').then(pickUpLocation => {
        cy.get('input#dropFtsAutocomplete').should('have.value', pickUpLocation)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a couple of ways of doing this (selecting multiple elements and testing the combination).

The way I've been doing it is something like

```
cy.get('input#ftsAutocomplete').then(ftsElement => {
  cy.get('input#dropFtsAutocomplete').should('have.value', ftsElement.textContent.trim())
})
```

Essentially, cypress command are asynchronous, so you can handle them in a similar way to promises.

You may have to fiddle with the exact syntax for getting the text value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Richard

Comment: However, it does not work as I got the error: .trim() not defined.

Comment: It is an example only - that is why I said you may have to fiddle with the exact syntax. Surely you can work out how to get text values from an element and compare them?